# Mustache lexer class

Tags: c++, c++14, lexical-analysis

I am trying to create a mustache interpreter.
I have started implementing the lexer parts.

Here are the classes:

#### Lexer.h

```
#ifndef LEXER_H
#define LEXER_H

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>      // std::out_of_range
#include <cstdio>       //EOF
#include "LexerElement.h"

namespace mustache {
    constexpr size_t min_string_len = 4;

    enum class Mode {
        TEXT,
        TAG_END_SEARCH
    };

    class Lexer {
        std::string m_text;

        std::string m_TagStart{"{{"};
        std::string m_TagEnd{"}}"};

        std::size_t m_position{0};
        std::size_t m_position_marker{0};
        std::string::size_type m_size;

        std::vector<LexerElement> m_elements;

        const char getChar() const noexcept;

        void charBack() noexcept {
            m_position--;
        }

        void charNext() noexcept {
            m_position++;
        }

        void mark_position() noexcept {
            m_position_marker = m_position;
        }

        void reset_position_to_marker() noexcept {
            m_position = m_position_marker;
        }

        bool isTagPart(std::string part) noexcept;

        bool isTagStart() noexcept {
            return isTagPart(m_TagStart);
        }

        bool isTagEnd() noexcept {
            return isTagPart(m_TagEnd);
        }

        void lex();
    public:
        Lexer(const std::string &str);
        virtual ~Lexer();

        void lex(const std::string &str);

        void dump_elements() const ;

        std::vector<LexerElement> getElements() const noexcept;

    };
}
#endif /* LEXER_H */
```

#### Lexer.cpp

```
#include "Lexer.h"
#include <iostream>

namespace mustache {

    Lexer::Lexer(const std::string &str) {
        lex(str);
    }

    Lexer::~Lexer() {
    }

    void Lexer::dump_elements() const {

        for (const auto &i : m_elements) {
            std::cout << i.getData() << '\n';
        }
    }

    std::vector<LexerElement> Lexer::getElements() const noexcept {
        return m_elements;
    }

    const char Lexer::getChar() const noexcept {
        try {
            return m_text.at(m_position);
        } catch (const std::out_of_range& oor) {
            return EOF;
        }
    }

    bool Lexer::isTagPart(std::string part) noexcept {
        mark_position();
        bool is_tag = false;

        for (const char &s : part) {
            if (s == getChar()) {
                charNext();
                is_tag = true;
                continue;
            }

            is_tag = false;
            break;
        }

        if (is_tag == false) {
            reset_position_to_marker();
        }
        return is_tag;
    }

    void Lexer::lex(const std::string &str) {
        if (str.size() <= min_string_len) {
            throw "String too small";
        }

        m_text = str;
        m_size = str.size();

        lex();
    }

    void Lexer::lex() {
        Mode mode = Mode::TEXT;
        size_t pos = 0;

        while (getChar() != EOF) {
            switch (mode) {
                case Mode::TEXT:
                    if (isTagStart()) {
                        if (m_position > 0) {
                            size_t len = m_position - m_TagEnd.length() - pos;
                            m_elements.emplace_back(m_text.substr(pos, len));

                            pos = m_position - m_TagEnd.length();
                        }

                        mode = Mode::TAG_END_SEARCH;
                    }
                    break;

                case Mode::TAG_END_SEARCH:
                    if (isTagEnd()) {
                        m_elements.emplace_back(m_text.substr(pos, m_position - pos), LexerElementTypes::TAG);

                        pos = m_position;
                        mode = Mode::TEXT;
                    }
                    break;
            }

            charNext();
        }
    }
}
```

#### LexerElement.h

```
#ifndef LEXERELEMENT_H
#define LEXERELEMENT_H

#include <string>

namespace mustache {

    enum class LexerElementTypes {
        TAG,
        TEXT
    };

    class LexerElement {
        std::string m_data;
        LexerElementTypes m_type;
    public:

        LexerElement(std::string data, LexerElementTypes m = LexerElementTypes::TEXT) : m_data(data), m_type(m) {
        };

        std::string getData() const {
            return m_data;
        }
    };
}
#endif /* LEXERELEMENT_H */
```

The full project can be seen [on github](https://github.com/AntonioCS/mustachecpp/tree/2f64291fceed7e5627d34461dcaa34bec9d004a9).
Any advice on how to improve the makefile would be greatly appreciated.

#### makefile

```
BIN=mustachecpp
BUILD_DIR=./build
OBJ_DIR=./obj
TARGET=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(BIN)
CFLAGS=-std=c++14 -Wall -g -Werror
LDFLAGS=
LDLIBS=
CC=g++
SRC_DIR=./src
SRC=$(shell find $(SRC_DIR) -name '*.cpp')
HEADERS=$(shell find $(SRC_DIR) -name '*.h')
#https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html
OBJ=$(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/,$(notdir $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(SRC))))
TEST_MAIN=$(OBJ_DIR)/tests-main.o

#http://stackoverflow.com/a/1951111/8715
dir_guard=@mkdir -p $(@D)


.PHONY: clean

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
    $(dir_guard)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)

tests: $(TEST_MAIN) $(OBJ) tests/LexerTest.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(BUILD_DIR)/$@ $^ $(LDLIBS)


#To cause recompile when .h files are change
$(OBJ): $(SRC) $(HEADERS)
    $(dir_guard)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $? $(LDLIBS)
#Put all the object files in the correct directory
    @mv *.o $(OBJ_DIR)


$(TEST_MAIN): tests/tests-main.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $(TEST_MAIN) $^


clean:
    rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)/* $(OBJ_DIR)/*
```

Answer (score 2):

## A Makefile review

Your object files should not each depend on *all* the headers.  You'll find that doing so will not be a problem now, but will waste a lot of your time as your project grows.  Instead, generate the dependencies automatically - e.g. following [Paul D. Smith's paper](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/).

Use `CXX` and `CXXFLAGS` for C++ compilation, not `CC` and `CFLAGS`.

It's best to run make in the *target* directory, and (if necessary) use VPATH to find the sources.  If you need to generate several targets using the same Makefile (e.g. for multi-platform builds), you can do that:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
make -C arm -f ../Makefile ARCH=arm
make -C x86 -f ../Makefile ARCH=x86
make -C sparc -f ../Makefile ARCH=sparc
```

If you must insist on doing it the other way around, at least save yourself duplicating built-in `$(COMPILE.cc)` and `$(LINK.cc)`.

---

Suggested Makefile, as a starting point:

```make
ifndef TOP
# Re-run Make in the build directory
OBJDIR=build

.PHONY: $(OBJDIR)
$(OBJDIR):
    +@test -d $@ || mkdir -p $@
    +@test -d $@/.d || mkdir -p $@/.d
    +@$(MAKE) --no-print-directory -C $@ -f ../Makefile TOP=.. $(MAKECMDGOALS)

Makefile: ;

%:: $(OBJDIR) ; : 

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) -r $(OBJDIR)

.SUFFIXES:

else
# We're in the build directory

OBJS = Lexer.o LexerTest.o tests-main.o

LexerTest: $(OBJS)
    $(LINK.cc) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@

VPATH = $(TOP)/src $(TOP)/tests

default: $(OBJS)


#Dependency generation, from http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/

DEPDIR := .d
DEPFLAGS = -MT $@ -MMD -MP -MF $(DEPDIR)/$*.Td

CXXFLAGS += $(DEPFLAGS)

POSTCOMPILE = @mv -f $(DEPDIR)/$*.Td $(DEPDIR)/$*.d && touch $@

%.o : %.c
%.o : %.c $(DEPDIR)/%.d
    $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
    $(POSTCOMPILE)

%.o : %.cpp
%.o : %.cpp $(DEPDIR)/%.d
    $(COMPILE.cc) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
    $(POSTCOMPILE)

$(DEPDIR)/%.d: ;
.PRECIOUS: $(DEPDIR)/%.d

include $(wildcard $(patsubst %,$(DEPDIR)/%.d,$(basename $(SRCS))))

endif
```

Comment: I will try to read that paper carefully and see if I can understand all the rules in the makefile. Thanks!